# tnn architecture suitable for distributed learning?

Tags: federated-learning

I am working on tnn, i found that its not working like other neural networks like they have layers and weights. my question is that tnn can be used  with federated learning in which we trained model on clients and only send the model weights to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer architecture is not different from other architectures, in the sense that it has layers, trainable parameters and is trained with gradient descent techniques. Therefore, it can be subject to federated learning.

However, Transformer models are normally very large in comparison with other architectures like LSTMs, and pose problems in the federated setup, specifically slow and unstable convergence.

You may have a look at variants of the Transformer specially made for the federated setup, e.g.: [*Federated Learning with Dynamic Transformer for Text to Speech*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.08795) (INTERSPEECH'21)

Comment: The Transformer from your link seems to be a standard one directly applied to time series, so it is possible that you also find the problems described in the paper I linked. Nevertheless, given the high variability between hyperparameter sets, only experimentation will give you the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with split learning. Maybe you should create a new question specifically for that.